# How to hide labels in a form class in symfony4?

Tags: symfony4

is there a way to hide label from form field in symfony 4?. This is my coding.

```
          $builder
                ->add('min', TextType::class, array('attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'min date',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'id' => 'min')))
                ->add('max', TextType::class, array('attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'max date',
                        'label' => false,
                        'id' => 'max')));
```

Even though I added `'label' => false,` label still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put in in the array of `attr` where it does not belong. This works:

```
$builder
    ->add('min', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'min date',
            'required' => false,
            'id' => 'min')))
    ->add('max', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'max date',
            'id' => 'max')));
```